# How to create a Privacy Preservinng Algorithmic Stablecoin in Ethereum

Tags: token, ethereum, privacy, erc20

How to create privacy focus algorithmic stable coin on ethereum
I want to create a algorithmic stablecoin on the top of ethereum platform
please suggest any reference, website, code

Comment: stable coins do not exist in nature, since nothing is stable. Even US Dollar can drop 50% in value, or rise 50% in value. You can watch the example of "stability" on WTI Oil chart, when it went to -40 bucks per barrel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Privacy Preserving Tokens can be created in Ethereum Network using the Confidential Token zkERC20 standard ( EIP - 1724 ). Please refer to the [following EIP Specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/1724). There are good reference implementations of Algorithmic Stablecoins in Ethereum such as XUSD. Please check the following [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/XUSDStable/xusd) for further details of the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

To create a pricay stablecoin you need to master

- Privacy protecting cryptography like zkSnarks
- Monetary theory
- Central banking
- Smart contracts
- Blockchain theory
- Frontend, backend programming
- Devops of infrastructure

Generally, this is worth of 6-7 years of studies. So I suggest enrolling into a university.